# Javascript regex for extracting certain part of string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need to extract certain part of Javascript string. I was thinking to do it with regex, but couldn't come up with one which does it correctly.

String can have variable length & can contain all possible characters in all possible combinations.

What I need to extract from it, is 10 adjacent characters, that match one of next two possible combinations:

1. 9 numbers & 1 letter "X" (capital letter "X", not X as variable letter!)
2. 10 numbers

So, if input string is this: "[1X,!?X22;87654321X9]ddee", it should return only "87654321X9".

I hope I've explained it good enough. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Regex will work:

`\d{9}X|\d{8}X\d|\d{7}X\d{2}|\d{6}X\d{3}|\d{5}X\d{4}|\d{4}X\d{5}|\d{3}X\d{6}|\d{2}X\d{7}|\d{1}X\d{8}|\d{10}|X\d{9}`

As described, It need to match 9 digits and any letter, and the letter can be at any position of the sequence.

```
\d{9}X # will match 9 digits and a letter in the end
\d{8}X\d # will match 8 digits a lettter then a digit again
... 
\d{1}X\d{8} # will match 1 digits a lettter then 8 digits
\{10} # will match 10 digits
```

Edited to match only X

Comment: sorry, but you didn't understand me - "X" doesn't represent ANY letter, but just CAPITAL letter X (eks). This works for any letter, which is not acceptable

Comment: it doesn't work for sequence starting with "X" - "X123456789" for example.

Comment: Yes, I don't know if OP wanted a sequence starting with a X, as I stated in my previous comment, he shoult append `|X\d{9}` at the end

Comment: i've appended it, now it works as it should. please edit your answer to include it, just for convinience and other users. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this much simpler regex:

```
/(?!\d*X\d*X)[\dX]{10}/
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?!\d*X\d*X)  # negative lookahead to fail the match if there are 2 X ahead
[\dX]{10}     # match a digit or X 10 times
```

Since more than one `X` is not allowed due to use of negative lookahead, this regex will only allow either 10 digits or ekse 9 digits and a single `X`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJ1aZ1/7)

This regex has few advantages over the other answer:

- Much simpler regex that is easier to read and maintain
- Takes less than half steps to complete which can be substantial difference on larger text.

Comment: thanks, can you tell me how to implement it, for example if input string is var input, how can I get output string (var output) using this regex?

Comment: It will not match 87654321X9

Comment: @anubhava yes it seems to work, but I've already accepted Koala 's answer. Thanks for your effort though!

Comment: @anubhava Your regex will match 87XXX421X9

Comment: Not quite correct - I tried this in Regex101 `87123X219X0` and it matched the first 9 characters `87123X219`.

Comment: Yet, you can have that occurring in a longer string of characters.

Comment: @vlaz: I've enhanced this regex.

Comment: It will not match anything in `87654321X9X` text, for example